# How to display a user's webform submissions?

Tags: webforms

I would like the user's profile page to have a block that shows their submissions to several [webform]s. So if I go to Chris's user page, it will show the basic fields and also a block of Chris's answers to webform1 and maybe another block with Chris's answers to webform2.

Any suggestions?